# Cleansing the value of a bound form field

Tags: python, django

I have a django form -

```
{{ field }}
```

This gives me the following HTML:

```
<input id="id_producers" type="text" class="long-input" value="[Lawrence Bender]" />
```

I need to clean the value attribute. I've written the following templatetag to do so:

```
{{ field|clean_list_string }}

def clean_list_string(field):
    value = field.value()
    if str(value).startswith('[') and str(value).endswith(']'):
        value = ast.literal_eval(value)
        if str(value)[1] == '(':
            value = ', '.join('(' + ', '.join(i) + ')' for i in value)
        else:
            value = ', '.join(value)

    return ??? (value)
```

How would I return the correct bound method such that the HTML returned has the changed value:

```
<input id="id_producers" type="text" class="long-input" value="Lawrence Bender" />
```

Comment: This is wrong in so many ways. First of all why the `value` is not cleaned in the first place? This should happen at the form level and not at the template level.

Comment: @rantanplan: this is a serialized field, and it makes it much easier to store the information as a list in this case.

Comment: Is it impossible to sanitize the data before sending it to the template?

Comment: You're talking about changing the internal state of the form. It would be much better *and* easier to do it with javascript on the DOM level.